# I cant understand what is causing my computer lag when nothing is running

Tags: windows-10, gpu, operating-systems, amd-radeon, lag

[image]

To try and describe what is happening, I have disabled all startup items that task manager brings up and have rebooted my pc.

Like the picture shows every half second it bounces from 19% GPU usage to 100% usage constantly.

This is also appearing as the background loading symbol next to my curser.

This did not happen until I bought the Razer Kraken ultimate headset and plugged them in and downloaded the drivers.

I have a Radeon RX 590 Series GPU (driver version 27.20.2001.9003), AMD Ryzen 7 1700X Eight-Core Processor with 16GB of Ram running Windows 64-bit.

What do I do, because this is happening without any razer background processes running and even running google chrome is now a pain.

Comment: What hard drive is in your system?